# How to set argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS for subparsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I don't want to get the unset options in the argument namespace. But `argparse.SUPPRESS` seems not pass on to subparsers.
The following code `print(args)` got the result. Since sub_arg2 and sub_args3 is not set, how to  get ride of them in the namespace?

> Namespace(sub_arg1='1', sub_arg2=[], sub_arg3=None, subparser='sub1')

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
# parser.add_argument('main_arg1')
# parser.add_argument('main_arg2', nargs='*')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser')
sparser = subparsers.add_parser('sub1')
sparser.add_argument('sub_arg1')
sparser.add_argument('sub_arg2', nargs='*')
sparser.add_argument('sub_arg3', nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args('sub1 1'.split())
print(args)
```

Comment: Main parser settings are not passed on to the subparsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_parser` takes any arguments the `ArgumentParser` constructor takes:

```
sparser = subparsers.add_parser('sub1', argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```